# link background not changing according to what i want

Tags: css

[Here is my code example](https://jsbin.com/yibixoriqe/edit?html,css,output)

The `.navbar` has `0.5 transparency` and also do not want the background of links changed when hovering. (right now background is white)

If i use `navbar-default` class then i can change background of list items and links but not able to do the `transparency` thing. And if i dont use `navbar-default`/inverse i am able to do `navbar` transparent but links have some `background` property on hover, which i am not able to override.

HTML

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img class="logo" src="images/brand.png"></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
 .navbar {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   font-family: avro;
 }

 .nav li a:hover {
   background: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you need to override boostrap style with `!important`. Besides this I would not recommend to use `background:none`; you only need to override the `background-color` property so I would recommend to add this css:

```
.nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  /* smooth override with important */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was replaced by bootstrap

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee; <--
}
```

you should try

```
.nav li a:hover {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I think replacing `background-color: #eee` with `background:none` is not the best idea, because then you cant use anything else as a background (hard reset).

Comment: @GerritHalfmann ya, you right. But i think in his case, he use background: none for some reason or can reset background-color without !important like kathara answer. .navbar .nav>li>a:focus, .navbar .nav>li>a:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following which doesn't need an `!important`:

```
.navbar .nav>li>a:focus, .navbar .nav>li>a:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

If possible `!important` should be avoided...

The more detailed you can define the element to be changed in css the more important it gets. So adding `.navbar` is better defined than just `.nav>li>a:hover` and thus is more important to css which means that the lesser defined is being overwritten ;)